# Does Xamarin.Forms TimePicker support behavior?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, prism

In my Xamarin.Forms project (with Prism, Android) I'm trying to implement the EventToCommandBehavior to a DatePicker as well as to a TimePicker in order to transfer the selected values. XAML looks like this:

```
            <DatePicker x:Name="DatePicker"
                        Format="D"
                        HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                        Margin="60, 0, 60, 0">
                <DatePicker.Behaviors>
                    <b:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="DateSelected"
                                              Command="{Binding DateSelectedCommand}"
                                              EventArgsConverter="{StaticResource DateSelectedConv}"/>
                </DatePicker.Behaviors>
            </DatePicker>

            <TimePicker x:Name="TimePicker"
                        HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                        Margin="60, 0, 60, 0">
                <TimePicker.Behaviors>
                    <b:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="TimeChanged"
                                              Command="{Binding TimeSelectedCommand}"
                                              EventArgsConverter="{StaticResource TimeSelectedConv}">

                    </b:EventToCommandBehavior>
                </TimePicker.Behaviors>
            </TimePicker>
```

In the ViewModel of this SettingsPage I have

```
    public ICommand DateSelectedCommand { get; set; }
    public ICommand TimeSelectedCommand { get; set; }

    private void NotifyDateSelected(DateTime date)
    {
        MessagingCenter.Send<SettingsPageViewModel, DateTime>(this, "dateChanged", date);
    }

    private void NotifyTimeSelected(TimeSpan timeSpan)
    {
        MessagingCenter.Send<SettingsPageViewModel, TimeSpan>(this, "timeChanged", timeSpan);
    }
```

The Convert method of the TimeSelectedConverter is

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var eventArgs = value as TimeChangedEventArgs;
        if (eventArgs == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("Expected TimeChangedEventArgs as value", "value");

        return new TimeSpan(eventArgs.HourOfDay, eventArgs.Minute, 0);
    }
```

The ViewModel of the consuming OverviewPage subscribes like this

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<SettingsPageViewModel, DateTime>(this, "dateChanged",
            (settingsPageViewModel, date) =>
            {
                Update();
            });

MessagingCenter.Subscribe<SettingsPageViewModel, TimeSpan>(this, "timeChanged",
            (settingsPageViewModel, timeSpan) =>
            {
                Update();
            });
```

This works fine with the DatePicker. However, as soon as I add the EventToCommandBehavior to the TimePicker the app crashes. Maybe TimePicker does not support behavior?

Comment: Did you find an answer?  Just hit the same issue